# C++ Cross-Platform webcam streaming over sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, streaming, cross-platform, webcam

I have a network of XP/Vista/7 machines most with webcams and a Linux machine which I use to administer the network.

What I need to do is create a program that runs on the Linux machine to  administer the webcams on the windows boxes, basically being able to activate any number of chosen webcams and have the video streamed and displayed on the linux machine.

What methods would I need to use to do this? Obviously multithreaded sockets but what libs or apis could i use to get the data across and viewable in real-time?

Comment: Just use Skype. Set the option to automatically accept incoming calls and the option to send video at call start.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd use:

1. OpenCV (For capturing the video from the webcam)
2. Qt (for the network and UI)
3. ffmpeg (For encoding the video)

Answer (score 1):

See my Skype comment above.  But if you are wanting to do something with your own code, you could look at using [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).  You could probably get an entire solution working with their command line tools and shell scripts.